# How can I implement a variable as a parameter into the getChild method?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am trying to assign the URLs from a content node to the posters that I am scrolling through in my row list. However, I can only hard code the parameter into the code. I want this to be dynamic as I will be having a large amount of URLs/posters.

I've tried to use `m.RowList.rowItemFocused` and pop out the second value in the array, assign that second value a variable and throw that variable in the `getChild()` method.

I've also tried switching the type that I receive from popping out that number because I thought there was some kind of string/integer mismatch but that didn't work either. I used `SetInt()`

I've tried setting a counter and incrementing that counter each time key = "right".

I've tried extracting the row number by using array notation but even when I console out a number, that number won't work inside the getChild method.

Pop method:

```
 myValue = m.CVRowList.rowItemFocused.pop()
 m.videoContent.url = m.videoContent.getChild(myValue).url
 m.video.content = m.videoContent
```

Array notation method:

```
 myValue = m.RowList.rowItemFocused[1]
 m.videoContent.url = m.videoContent.getChild(myValue).url
 m.video.content = m.videoContent
```

Counter method:

```
 focusedItem = 0

 if (key = "right") then

      focusedItem++
      m.videoContent.url = m.videoContent.getChild(focusedItem).url
      m.video.content = m.videoContent

 end if
```

One of the errors I've been seeing:

```
 Type Mismatch. (runtime error &h18) in 
 pkg:/components/HomeScene.brs(52)
 m.videoContent.getChild(myValue).url
```

Comment: what's line 52 of HomeScene.brs?  Where is your content getting assigned to your rowlist?

Comment: Line 52 is this: `m.videoContent.url = m.videoContent.getChild(myValue).url`

My content is being assigned to the row list posters in a content node, separate from the video content node. The Video node is name `videoContent` and that has all of the URLs that should be playing on `rowItemSelected`

Answer (score 0):

you want to get the `rowItemFocused` field of your rowlist, then use that as the index to find the data within the content that was assigned to the rowlist. Not the rowlist items themselves: you need to go back to the original content that was assigned to the rowlist.

```
myValue = m.CVRowList.rowItemFocused ' gives an integer (don't use pop() here!)
m.videoContent.url = m.videoContent.getChild(myValue).url
' is m.videoContent your video's content or your rowlist's content?  Can't be both!
m.video.content = m.videoContent
```

If I knew where your content was (that probably came from a task field) I would do this:

```
myValue = m.CVRowList.rowItemFocused ' gives an integer
videoContent = createObject("RoSGNode","ContentNode")
videoContent.url = #YOUR_CONTENT?#.getChild(myValue).url
m.video.content = videoContent
```

Comment: This looks good with the exception that `m.CVRowList.rowItemFocused` comes back as an array with two digits. To get around that I used `m.CVRowList.rowItemFocused[1]` to get the second digit (the column) in the array. However, even when add that to a variable and place that in the `getChild()` method, I still get an error on `videoContent.url = videoContent.getChild(myValue).url`

The error is `Backtrace:
#0  Function setvideo() As Void
   file/line: pkg:/components/HomeScene.brs(54)`

`setVideo()` is the function that this script lives in and you're seeing all of it

Comment: I'm thinking this might be a type issue because when I hardcode `1` into `getChild()`, I see that it is an `integer` while the value I get from `myValue` is a `roInt` - might be grasping at straws here though

Comment: try adding a line for debug before the line that crashes; `print videoContent.getChild(myValue)` and see what datatype the output is, and what fields ./ values it has?